# Taking pagination out of render method (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a basic pagination feature within my Reactjs website.

The issue I am having is I have created this within the render function so often this may not appear unless the page is refreshed.

I am not sure as of how I would fix this without doing something unsecured like make the important variables global.

This is my render function which handles the page pagination.

```
  render() {
    // Logic for displaying current todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    console.log(this.state.questions);
    if (!this.state.FullDetailsPageToken) {
      if (this.state.questions.length) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Completed Workstation Assessments
            </h2>
            <ul>
              <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
                Workstation Assessments
              </button>
              <Link to="./admin-center">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
              </Link>
              <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
              </Link>
              <DropdownButton
                style={{ float: "right" }}
                id="dropdown-basic-button"
                title="Completed"
              >
                <Dropdown.Item>
                  {" "}
                  <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                    In Progress
                  </Link>
                </Dropdown.Item>
              </DropdownButton>{" "}
            </ul>

            <ul>
              {currentTodos.map(function(r, index) {
                return (
                  <div className="jumbotron">
                    <Questions
                      workStation={r.AssignedWorkstation}
                      date={r.Date}
                      completeToken={r.QuestionStatus}
                      RUId={r.RUId}
                      WSAId={r.WSAId}
                    ></Questions>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
              <div
                style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
                id="page-numbers"
              >
                {pageNumbers.map(number => {
                  return (
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      key={number}
                      id={number}
                      onClick={this.handleClick}
                    >
                      {number}
                    </button>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      } else if (!this.state.questions.length) {
        return (
          <>
            {" "}
            <div>
              <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                Completed Workstation Assessments
              </h2>

              <ul>
                <br />
                <br />{" "}
                <div>
                  <h6> </h6>
                </div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the whole class

```
class AdminWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      viewDetails: false,

      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 10,
      pageNumbers: [],
      FullDetailsPageToken: false
    };
    this.getQuestionByUniqueDate = this.getQuestionByUniqueDate.bind(this);
    // this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  };

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(`QuestionResponses array ${this.state.questions}`);

        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
  }

  getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (
        !results.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
        !results.find(
          q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
        )
      ) {
        results.push(questions[i]);
        this.setState({ amountOfWorkstations: results.length });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    // Logic for displaying current todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    console.log(this.state.questions);
    if (!this.state.FullDetailsPageToken) {
      if (this.state.questions.length) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Completed Workstation Assessments
            </h2>
            <ul>
              <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
                Workstation Assessments
              </button>
              <Link to="./admin-center">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
              </Link>
              <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
              </Link>
              <DropdownButton
                style={{ float: "right" }}
                id="dropdown-basic-button"
                title="Completed"
              >
                <Dropdown.Item>
                  {" "}
                  <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                    In Progress
                  </Link>
                </Dropdown.Item>
              </DropdownButton>{" "}
            </ul>

            <ul>
              {currentTodos.map(function(r, index) {
                return (
                  <div className="jumbotron">
                    <Questions
                      workStation={r.AssignedWorkstation}
                      date={r.Date}
                      completeToken={r.QuestionStatus}
                      RUId={r.RUId}
                      WSAId={r.WSAId}
                    ></Questions>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
              <div
                style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
                id="page-numbers"
              >
                {pageNumbers.map(number => {
                  return (
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      key={number}
                      id={number}
                      onClick={this.handleClick}
                    >
                      {number}
                    </button>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      } else if (!this.state.questions.length) {
        return (
          <>
            {" "}
            <div>
              <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                Completed Workstation Assessments
              </h2>

              <ul>
                <br />
                <br />{" "}
                <div>
                  <h6> </h6>
                </div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this not within the render function or of fixing the code so that the pagination is rendered properly.

Thanks!

EDIT---
Tried to change this to work as shown. Still no success not nothing displays.

```
class AdminWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      viewDetails: false,

      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 10,
      pageNumbers: [],
      // FullDetailsPageToken: false,
      loadingToken: true,
      indexOfLastTodo: null,
      indexOfFirstTodo: null,
      currentTodos: null,
      currentTodos: null
    };
    this.getQuestionByUniqueDate = this.getQuestionByUniqueDate.bind(this);
    // this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  };

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(`QuestionResponses array ${this.state.questions}`);

        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
    this.state.indexOfLastTodo =
      this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    this.state.indexOfFirstTodo =
      this.state.indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    this.state.currentTodos = results.slice(
      this.state.indexOfFirstTodo,
      this.state.indexOfLastTodo
    );

    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
  }

  getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (
        !results.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
        !results.find(
          q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
        )
      ) {
        results.push(questions[i]);
        this.setState({ amountOfWorkstations: results.length });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ loadingToken: false });
  }

  render() {
    // Logic for displaying current todos
    // const indexOfLastTodo = this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    // const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    // const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    // const pageNumbers = [];
    // for (
    //   let i = 1;
    //   i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
    //   i++
    // ) {
    //   pageNumbers.push(i);
    // }

    console.log(this.state.questions);

    if (this.state.questions.length && !this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Completed Workstation Assessments
          </h2>

          <ul>
            <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
              Workstation Assessments
            </button>
            <Link to="./admin-center">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
            </Link>
            <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
            </Link>
            <DropdownButton
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              id="dropdown-basic-button"
              title="Completed"
            >
              <Dropdown.Item>
                {" "}
                <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                  In Progress
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>{" "}
          </ul>

          <ul>
            {this.state.currentTodos.map(function(r, index) {
              return (
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <Questions
                    workStation={r.AssignedWorkstation}
                    date={r.Date}
                    completeToken={r.QuestionStatus}
                    RUId={r.RUId}
                    WSAId={r.WSAId}
                  ></Questions>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <div
              style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
              id="page-numbers"
            >
              {this.state.pageNumbers.map(number => {
                return (
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    key={number}
                    id={number}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                    {number}
                  </button>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.questions.length && !this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <>
          {" "}
          <div>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Completed Workstation Assessments
            </h2>

            <ul>
              <br />
              <br />{" "}
              <div>
                <h6> </h6>
              </div>
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    } else if (this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <>
          <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Completed Workstation Assessments
          </h2>
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>LOADING</div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT -

Have added most recent update of the class. results are disaplying but pagination is not working.

```
class AdminWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      viewDetails: false,

      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 10,
      pageNumbers: [],
      // FullDetailsPageToken: false,
      loadingToken: true
    };
    this.getQuestionByUniqueDate = this.getQuestionByUniqueDate.bind(this);
    // this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState(
      {
        currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
      },
      () => this.updatePages()
    );
  };

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber });
  }

  updatePages() {
    // Logic Added Here
    const indexOfLastTodo = this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    this.setState({
      currentTodos: results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo)
    });
    // Saved the currentTodos value inside the state.
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      // Saved the pageNumbers value inside the state
      this.setState({
        pageNumbers: [...this.state.pageNumbers, i]
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(`QuestionResponses array ${this.state.questions}`);

        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
    this.updatePages();
  }

  getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (
        !results.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
        !results.find(
          q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
        )
      ) {
        results.push(questions[i]);
        this.setState({ amountOfWorkstations: results.length });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ loadingToken: false });
  }

  render() {
    // const indexOfLastTodo = this.state.currentPage * this.state.todosPerPage;
    // const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.todosPerPage;
    // const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    // const pageNumbers = [];
    // for (
    //   let i = 1;
    //   i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / this.state.todosPerPage);
    //   i++
    // ) {
    //   pageNumbers.push(i);
    // }

    // console.log(this.state.questions);

    if (this.state.questions.length && !this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <div>
          <PageTitle />

          <ul>
            <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
              Workstation Assessments
            </button>
            <Link to="./admin-center">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
            </Link>
            <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
            </Link>
            <DropdownButton
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              id="dropdown-basic-button"
              title="Completed"
            >
              <Dropdown.Item>
                {" "}
                <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                  In Progress
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>{" "}
          </ul>

          <ul>
            {this.state.currentTodos.map(function(r, index) {
              return (
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <Questions
                    workStation={r.AssignedWorkstation}
                    date={r.Date}
                    completeToken={r.QuestionStatus}
                    RUId={r.RUId}
                    WSAId={r.WSAId}
                  ></Questions>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <div
              style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
              id="page-numbers"
            >
              {this.state.pageNumbers.map(number => {
                return (
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    key={number}
                    id={number}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                    {number}
                  </button>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.questions.length && !this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <>
          {" "}
          <div>
            <PageTitle />

            <ul>
              <br />
              <br />{" "}
              <div>
                <h6> </h6>
              </div>
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    } else if (this.state.loadingToken) {
      return (
        <>
          <PageTitle />
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>LOADING</div>

          <div className="loader center">
            <i className="fa fa-cog fa-spin" />
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the logic inside componentDidMount life-cycle function?

Comment: Line 127:14:  'currentTodos' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 144:16:  'pageNumbers' is not defined   no-undef

Comment: As it throws that error

Comment: You are a hero if you could post one with code you woudl be a life saver

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could implement a pagination component:

```js
const Pagination = ({
  onChange,
  total,
  pageSize,
  current,
}) => {
  return React.useMemo(() => {
    const pages = [
      ...new Array(Math.ceil(total / pageSize)),
    ].map((_, index) => index + 1);
    if (pages.length === 1) {
      //do not display if there is only one page
      return '';
    }
    return (
      <label>
        page
        <select
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
          value={current}
        >
          {pages.map(page => (
            <option key={page} value={page}>
              {page}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
    );
  }, [current, onChange, pageSize, total]);
};
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ item }) {
  return <li>{item}</li>;
});
const List = React.memo(function List({ items }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item} item={item} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = React.useState(2);
  const changeItemsPerPage = React.useCallback(e => {
    setItemsPerPage(e.target.value);
    setPage(1); //reset page to 1
  }, []);
  const changePage = React.useCallback(
    page => setPage(Number(page)),
    []
  );
  const items = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      data.slice(
        (page - 1) * itemsPerPage,
        page * itemsPerPage
      ),
    [itemsPerPage, page]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          items per page
          <select
            value={itemsPerPage}
            onChange={changeItemsPerPage}
          >
            {[2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11].map(p => (
              <option value={p} key={p}>
                {p}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Pagination
          onChange={changePage}
          total={data.length}
          pageSize={itemsPerPage}
          current={page}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <List items={items}></List>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```